# Spotify web api doesn't work with ios devices

Tags: javascript, angular, spotify

I'm building a webapp with Spotify and Deezer api where I can listen and control (next, previous, pause, play) music.
Everything works well on Android devices or on desktop, but not with IOS devices (chrome / safari). I can control music from another spotify device: for example if I have Spotify app opened on my computer, I can start and switch tracks from the iphone, but the music never come from to it.

What I did is simple, after getting token, I check all the connected devices from a user, and active mobile if it exist.
But iphone device is never recognized, I put a log and I can see there is no device if I try to play only from the iphone.
After that, I just play the songs:

```
public playAlbum(track: Track, position?: number) {
const token = window.localStorage.getItem('wmg-as-token');
const body = {
  'uris': [track.uri],
  'offset': {
    'position': 0
  },
  'position_ms': position ? position : 0
};

return this.http.put(`${this.uri}/me/player/play`, body,  {headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token}});
```

}

**I'm not using Web Playback SDK**, I'm using api endpoint : https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/player/

I have lot of code that I can post (for exemple aout the transfer device), but I don't want to put too much code to not afraid readers. Maybe I just miss an information about ios.

If anyone has an idea I'm here..

**EDIT :**

I tried to launch website from IOS Simulator, and saw there are some error logs like this :
[image: Api error]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Spotify has two APIs:
One for the web: https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/
And one for iOS: https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/ios/

There is a possibility that they differ slightly, please check which one you used. 
(This would have been a comment, but im <50 rep)

Comment: I'm using web api, the other one is for native ios app.

Answer (score 1):

The Web Playback SDK does not support iOS browsers:

https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-playback-sdk/#supported-browsers

Comment: Ignore my previous (deleted) comment, I didn't see that you speak about Web Playback SDK. I'm not using it, I'm using /play, /pause...  endpoints to start music from the spotify app.

Answer (score 0):

Apple does not allow the web player to automatically play due to a program flow. It needs to be directly using a html button that triggers the Player instance you created on the onSpotifyWebPlaybackSDKReady handler.
This code will probably work for you, with the trade off that it is another step for the user to hear music. That's the apple way of doing things.

The alternative you have is to build a native iOs app, which allows you to control the spotify device itself, which doesn't have this problem

Hope this helps

```
  window.onSpotifyWebPlaybackSDKReady = function() {
    const player = new Spotify.Player({
      name: 'your app',
      getOAuthToken: cb => { cb(access_token); }
    });

    window.player = player

    document.getElementById('togglePlay').onclick = function() {
       player.togglePlay();
    };
```